# Output a two dimensional array using basic C language

Tags: c, arrays, printf

I'm trying to make a program that can input 10 student's name, but I just don't know how to store them. I did the code below and I really think that there is no mistake, it is just a draft on how I would use the inputting of names. We are only allowed to use C language for this.

This is how I want my output to be:

```
List:
arr[0][50]=jason
arr[1][50]=jade
.
.
.
arr[10][50]=mark
```

But it just keeps showing an error, I can only run it before it shows the first equal.

Below is my code. Please pardon my syntax I am seriously new to coding.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define pf printf
#define sf scanf

#define ENTER 13
#define TAB 9
#define BKSP 8

main()
{
    char g7nameinput[0][50];
    char g7fname[10][50], g7mname[10][50], g7lname[10][50];
    char ch, choice;
    int incname, incnamelist=0, i, max=50;

    createstudent:
    pf("\n\nInput first name: ");
    incname=0;
    while(1)
    {
        ch=getch();

        if(ch==ENTER)
        {
            g7nameinput[0][incname]='\0';
            break;
        }
        else if(ch==BKSP)
        {
            if(incname>0)
            {
                incname--;
                pf("\b \b");
            }
        }
        else if(ch==TAB)
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            g7nameinput[0][incname]=ch;
            incname++;
            pf("%c",ch);
        }
    }
    pf("\nFirst Name inputted is %s",g7nameinput);
    pf("\n\nInputted correct? [Y/N]: ");
    sf("%c",&choice);

    if((choice=='Y')||(choice=='y'))
    {
        g7fname[incnamelist][50] = g7nameinput;
        incnamelist++;

        pf("\n\nList:");
        for(i=0;i<incnamelist;i++)
        {
            pf("\narr[%d][%d]=%s",i,max,g7fname[i][50]);
        }

        goto createstudent;
    }
    else
    {
        goto createstudent;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are `printf` and `scanf` really so long that you feel the need to abbreviate them with preprocessor macros?

Comment: I suggest you enlist the help of a good TA.  We're not set up for extended tutoring here.

Comment: Yes we're tasked to do a program with all of the C language syntax, and the code above was my attempt to make **a program that can input 10 student's name**. I don't know if it's a correct approach, but my friend told me that I could just make many variables (name1-name10), but the problem is we also need to get the middle name and the last name.

Comment: @fred idk our teacher did it first lmao

Comment: Between that and "tasked to do a program with all of the C language syntax" I'm having serious doubts about your teacher.

Comment: Well, although not illegal `goto` statements used in this way are not typical.  It leads to spaghetti code.  And using _all of the C language syntax_ is a pretty big order.  I am pretty sure there has never been a `C` program to date that has ever used _all_ of the syntax available to the `C` language :).

Comment: You need to be more specific about "showing an error" - which error, and with what input? Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*but I just don't know how to store them....*

Use an array of struct:

```
#define MAX_NAMES 10 //per your stated maximum

typedef struct {
  char first[80];
  char middle[80];
  char last[80];
}NAMES;

NAMES names[MAX_NAMES] = {0};//a container with space for 10 first, middle and last names
```

And a very simple way to input student names via a main function:

```
int main(void)
{
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<MAX_NAMES;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the First name of student %d\n", i+1);
        fgets(names[i].first, sizeof(names[i].first), stdin);
        printf("Enter the Middle name of student %d\n", i+1);
        fgets(names[i].middle, sizeof(names[i].middle), stdin);
        printf("Enter the Last name of student %d\n", i+1);
        fgets(names[i].last, sizeof(names[i].last), stdin);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help!!! i got to made one w/ struct as you mentioned and everything is okay now. thank you so much.

`struct studentname
    {
        char fname[50];
        char mname[50];
        char lname[50];
    } student[10];`

sorry if i derived your work, i honestly cannot use the fgets for our program

Comment: @DyrdKmp - No problem, This code is freely offered!  Is it your teacher that insists in not using `fgets()`?

Answer (score 0):

Outputting a 2 dimensional array is a simple task, you can think of it as an array within an array. All you need to do is iterate on both arrays, and print in whatever fashion you prefer.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int array[4][2] = { // 4 arrays, each has 2 elements
        { 1, 2 }, // array[0]
        { 3, 4 }, // array[1]
        { 5, 6 }, // array[2]
        { 7, 8 }, // array[3]
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) { // iterate on the 4 arrays we have
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; ++j) { // iterate on each element of those arrays
            printf("%d", array[i][j]); // print out that element
        }
    }
}
```

Now, think about how you can incorporate this into your program.