# Build new binary from C program

Tags: c, compilation, binary

I'm working on a C program, it's a custom shell that asks the user to set different options (IP, port, ...) and then allow the user to build a binary based on these informations. I was wondering what is the best way to build a new binary from within an existing program ?

EDIT: My question may have been a bit unclear. The new compiled binary is a simple TCP client that will connect to the specified IP and Port. I don't want this new binary to be dependant of a config file. How can i build this from my existing C program ? Should i write the IP and Port to a .c file and then compile it using `system("/bin/gcc ...")` ?

Comment: What binary? For what? Binary is the most general format for any data on the computer.

Comment: Unless you have really strange constraints, just build one executable that reads a config file. You can generate that config file however you want.

Comment: What is this "binary" and what does it do? Is it accetable to require GCC, Visual Studio, or similar to be pre-installed on the system, or do you need a self-contained solution?

Comment: By binary i meant a new C compiled program with gcc. The binary is basically just a simple TCP client that will connect to the specified IP and Port

Comment: Then you are asking about configuring the build? Do it with Makefile and conditional compilation (`#ifdef xxx` and such).

Comment: _"Should i write the IP and Port to a .c file and then compile it "_: that's probably the simplest thing to do.

Comment: ... but this sounds somewhat like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What are you _actually_ trying to achieve?

Comment: I want a C program that can dynamically generate a standalone TCP client binary with a specified IP / Port.

Comment: So you want a program that generates a program? I would think it is an XY problem indeed. Like you don't want it to depend on a config file, but you do want it to depend on another program? Does not make sense *to me*.

Comment: Exactly a program that generates a new program

Comment: Are command line arguments out of the question?  That depends on who the customer is for your program — if it's you, you'd probably be better served with a program that takes arguments (or a config file).  If they're naïve end-users who can't be trusted to type the command name correctly, let alone remember arguments like port numbers and host names, then a shell script that fixes those parameters and invokes a program that expects arguments can work well.  Or you can do as you propose.  But recompiling a program to change simple values is not usually a good idea.

Comment: If Jonathan Leffler's comment does not apply, then probably my previous comment applies.

Comment: Alright, so either using arguments (even though i can't use some in my case) or changing the IP and Port manually in a .c file. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are describing code generation and programmatically compiling a new executable.  There are many ways to do what you have described.  Here is a very simple (and very rough draft of a) set of steps to code gen, and compile:

1) Use *[printf, fgets calls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59180910/645128)* from existing program to prompt user for a specific set of input values
2) Convert command line numeric input values if necessary. (Using atoi(), or strtod() for example)
3) Open a file for write, (eg FILE *fp = fopen(filespec, "w");)
4) Using fputs(), send a series of lines to the file comprised of a C source file, including values from steps 1&2 from the user input.
   eg. `fputs("#include _some file_", fp);` (and other header files as needed)
   eg, `fputs("int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {", fp);`
       `fputs(...)` (all of the rest of your lines to make up the complete user defined code.)
       `fputs("return 0; }", fp);`
5) close the file:  `fclose(fp);`
6) Construct a *[gcc command line compile string](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/gcc-command-in-linux-with-examples/)* to be used on command line on the file you just created.
7) Using `popen()` (If available) or system() or if using Windows, something like *[this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/162546/send-command-and-get-response-from-windows-cmd-prompt-silently)* to send a command to the OS, to execute gcc (or other compiler) on the command line to create your executable.

Comment: That's exactly what i asked ! However can i use a pre-written C source file and just add some data (here IP and Port) to it ? Like some kind of search and replace in C ?

Comment: Yes, kind of.  If you have obtained user inputs from a very specific set of questions, as @Jonathan Leffler alluded to in his comments, and they are included in the text strings you prepare in your _code generation_ steps, then those values should be sufficient to define certain programmed in behaviors for your new executable.  Keep in mind, this is a very simple set of steps for the purpose of illustrating what it might look like to do what you have described.

Answer (score 1):

If you have ready code in C all the options (like ip or other parameters write to the another file for example userdata.c

```
#include "userdata.h"

unsigned char IP[4] = {212,34,56,78};
const char IPstring[] = "212.34.56.78";
const char DNSIPstring[] = "4.4.4.4";
const char defaultGatewayIPstring[] = "212.34.56.1";
/* etc etc */
```

and userdata.h

```
#ifndef USERTATA_H
#define USERTATA_H
extern unsigned char IP[];
extern const char IPstring[];
extern const char DNSIPstring[];
extern const char defaultGatewayIPstring[];
/* etc etc */
#endif
```

In your main program files just include the .h file. Do not forget to compile and link the .c file as well :)